# Ellipsize text inside a recycler view

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view in which I have a text view item which I want to ellipsize but this ellipsize is not happening at the recycler view level.

Item view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/service_info_slot_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.gojek.asphalt.aloha.text.AlohaTextView
        android:id="@+id/slot_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="I went to buy a chicken but there was no chicken to buy so I bought fish"
        app:aloha_typographyStyle="caption_moderate_book_default" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Recycler view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/service_info_slot_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/service_info_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:listitem="@layout/service_info_slot"
        tools:itemCount="3"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I think the recycler view is not able to calculate the width of the items properly to ellipsize them due to the horizontal orientation. The individual item is ellipsized but when in the context of recycler view they are not.

Comment: Set the layout and textView width to match_parent. The reason could also be a custom implementation of AlohaTextView.

Comment: You need to set specified width to textview. Like 100dp, 200dp...

Comment: Setting a specified width will ellipsize each item internally. I want it to ellipsize only on the last one.

What you said will result in something like

`I want to buy..  I want to buy...`

What I want is 

`I want to buy a chicken  I want...`

Also `match_parent` doesnt work and this is just a wrapper on top of text view which doesn't have any custom implementation which would affect this.

Comment: In that case you can do it programmatically in recycler view adapter only for last item.

Comment: how do we find where to elipisize in that case? as the item size can be varying and we don't know the cutoff point.